# Inequality Problem of examination

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that if $n > 2$, then $(n!)^2 > n^n$.

I cannot find any way out to these.Please help.

I tried break $n!$ and then argue but failed.

Comment: Is this a class where you would use induction?

Comment: Are you allowed to use Stirling approximation ?

Answer (score 2):

For $n=k, (k!)^2>k^k$

For $n=k+1,\{(k+)!\}^2=(k+1)^2\cdot(k!)^2>(k+1)^2\cdot k^k$

It is sufficient to prove $(k+1)^2\cdot k^k>(k+1)^{k+1}\iff k+1>\left(1+\frac1k\right)^k$

But $\left(1+\frac1k\right)^k<3$ See [this](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080408091208AAyIv5Z) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272245/proving-that-left-frac10-frac11-frac12-frac13-cdots)

Answer (score -1):

$$(n!)^2=1(n)\times2(n-1)\times3(n-2)\times \cdots n(1)$$
But
$$n\ge a+1 \implies a(n)\ge a(a+1)\implies (a+1)(n-a)\ge n$$
And equality is achieved iff $a=0$ or $a=n-1$. Since for $n>2$ we have $a=1\neq n-1$ in our product, we have the strict inequality $(n!)^2>n^n$.

Comment: No. Each term is *less*.

Comment: @martycohen Yes you are right! Fixed.